# How we can draw an image or any string along diagonal?

Tags: java-me

How we can draw an image or any string along diagonal, as usually they are drawn horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to rotate image 45 degrees? You need take third-patry lib for non-standard transforming or write it by yourself.

But all runtime transformations take much memory and CPU. The fastest way is keeping ready images in jar or downloading them via internet.